# How to benchmark (track CPU usage of) a short-lived command?

Tags: load, benchmarking, measurement

While I'm aware of commands such as `top` (with a number of equivalents listed [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/pranav/how-to-find-out-cpu-utilization-in-linux)), I'm not clear on how to capture the CPU usage of a "short-lived" process. For example, if I wanted to see the performance of the `ls` command, what could I do that would sample the load measurement frequently enough and fast enough to be of use?

Most existing answers I've seen on this topic use a loop that repeats something like `top` every *n* seconds, which isn't applicable for quick / short-lived commands, especially given that I won't have time to see the PID in time to feed it to said techniques. I might be able to use something from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414770/282034) since it seems to be sampling at pretty low timescales, but I suspect there's a more direct / less intense approach.

Comment: Can you instrument every run of your short-lived command, like `time ls`, or `perf stat ls` or `strace -c ls` to count time in system calls?  Or do you need to detect startup of short-lived processes?  system-wide `perf record -a` might work.

Comment: @PeterCordes `perf stat` and `strace -c` seem to do exactly what I need; thank you! If you can post this comment as an answer, I'll checkmark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can instrument every run of your short-lived command, you can measure wall-clock, user-CPU, and system-CPU time with  `time ls`.

Or for more details, there's `perf stat ls`.  Depending on your sysctl `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0` setting, you can use HW perf counters to measure CPU cycles / cache misses / etc. in kernel code as well as user-space.  It also does software events like page faults.  But for *very* short-lived commands like `ls`, `perf` will have significant startup overhead.  On Intel CPUs, `ocperf.py` is a wrapper for `perf` with more events.  See [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) for an example of using `ocperf.py` for an asm microbenchmark.

`strace -c ls` will count time spent in system calls.

---

If you can't run each short command under a measurement wrapper, a system-wide `perf record -a` might work.